# Unable to shift voiceover focus to a specific UICollectionView cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, accessibility, voiceover

I am using the following tried and tested code to get VoiceOver to select a certain UICollectionViewCell:

```
var indexPath = IndexPath(row: 4, section: 3)
if let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
      UIAccessibility.post(notification: UIAccessibility.Notification.screenChanged,
                                     argument: cell)
}
```

However, whatever cell I set the index path to, VoiceOver ignores this and always ends up selecting the last selected UICollectionViewCell.  Even if I deselect that cell beforehand using:

```
self.collectionView.selectItem(at: nil, animated: false, scrollPosition: .bottom)
```

Question 1. Has anyone come across this issue?  2. Is this another VoiceOver bug?  3. Does anyone have a workaround for it?

Comment: Try a delay (not great, but it usually works for me): `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(.now + 0.7) { UIAccessibility.post... }`

Comment: Nice idea.  Already tried this.  A delay all the way up to 5.0 and still didnt work.

Comment: Which version of iOS are you using? Have you seen the behavior on multiple versions?

Comment: Maybe this WWDC demo could help ⟹https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/2018/230/#how-to-render-a-carousel-perfectly-voiceover-understandable-2553 

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your cells have accessibility enabled and that they have a valid accessibility label.

As a test implementation, I added the following code in the `UICollectionViewDataSource`'s `cellForItemAt` method.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    
    let numberOfCells = 100
    
    // Set these values if you haven't
    cell.isAccessibilityElement = true
    cell.accessibilityLabel = "Cell \(indexPath.item) of \(numberOfCells))"
    
    return cell
}
```

Note: I got into trouble when the `collectionView` also had accessibility enabled. VoiceOver worked fine when only the cells had accessibility enabled.

Next, try calling your initial methods to get VoiceOver to select the collection view cell. I got some additional smoothness by first selecting the cell from the collectionView's `selectItem` method as shown below.

```swift
var indexPath = IndexPath(row: 4, section: 3)
if let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
    self.collectionView.selectItem(
        at: indexPath,
        animated: true,
        scrollPosition: [.centeredVertically, .centeredHorizontally]
    )
    UIAccessibility.post(
        notification: UIAccessibility.Notification.screenChanged,
        argument: cell
    )
}
```